# Touchables in react native

Tags: react-native, touchableopacity

I am trying to add some space in the middle of two touchable components wrapped in a view
How do i go about doing that, I will include my style sheet

```
  return (
        <>enter code here
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.scrollContainer}>
              <ScrollView
                horizontal
                pagingEnabled
                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
              >
                {images.map((image) => (
                  <Image key={image} style={styles.image} source={image} />
                ))}
              </ScrollView>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.btn}>
              `enter code here`<LinearGradient
            colors={["#0A5640", "#0A5640"]}
            style={{ alignItems: "center", borderRadius: 10 }}
          >
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("SignIn")}>
              <Text style={styles.btnAuth}>Sign In</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </LinearGradient>
          <LinearGradient
            colors={["#FFC72A", "#FFC72A"]}
            style={{ alignItems: "center", borderRadius: 10 }}
          >
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate("CreateAccount")}
            >
              <Text style={styles.btnAuth}>Sign Up</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </LinearGradient>
        </View>
      </View>
    </>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: "#0A5640",
  },
  scrollContainer: {
    height: "100%",
  },
  image: {
    width,
    height: "100%",
  },
  btnAuth: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    paddingHorizontal: 60,
    paddingVertical: 10,
    color: "#fff",
    marginLeft: 10,
  },
  btn: {
    color: "#fff",
    marginTop: 70,
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "space-around",
    alignContent: "space-between",
    zIndex: 200,
    paddingRight: 10,
    paddingLeft: 10,
    bottom: 3,
    position: "absolute",
  },
});
```

Comment: Pls format you code

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean the space between SignIn and SignUp button? You can use flex or width to define the touchableOpacity width. Is this something that you tried to achieve?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {Text,View,StyleSheet,TouchableOpacity,}from 'react-native';

    export default function App() {   return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.btn}>
              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnAuth}>
                <Text style={{color:'#000', fontSize:18}}>Sign In</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            
              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnAuth}>
                <Text style={{color:'#000', fontSize:18}}>Sign Up</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>   ); }
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({   container: { backgroundColor: '#0A5640', flex:1 },   btnAuth: {
        padding: 20,
        width : '45%',
        alignItems:'center',
        backgroundColor:'yellow'   },   btn: {
        color: '#fff',
        width: '100%',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'space-around',
        bottom: 3,
        position: 'absolute',   }, });
```

[image]